# C#: Changing a base class from one to another without changing the source code of the original

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiple-inheritance

I'll start with saying, I'm new to C#. My programming background is mostly python. I'm self taught so I don't have a huge understanding on all the terminology, so if you could answer in as plain English as possible, it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to find the best way to go about doing something that seems relatively simple, but there are a few constraints. There are two separate libraries that I am attempting to get to work together, but I don't/can't want to change the original ones.

This is kind of how the code is:

**Library A.**

```
class SomeClass : CommonParentClass {}
```

**Library B**.

```
class SimilarParentClass : CommonParentClass {}
```

I need Library A's **SomeClass** to actually inherit from Library B's **SimilarParentClass** which derived from the SAME **CommonParentClass**.

The simple solution I see is just change the source of Library A, but then every time Library A gets updated I will have to go in and change all the occurrences of **CommonParentClass** to **SimilarParentClass**.

The solution I'm thinking might be needed but would like some help with:

Create an interface for **SomeClass** and an interface for **SimilarParentClass** then create a new class that implements both interfaces. Does this sound right? The truth is I really only need a single method from **SimilarParentClass** but I need all the things from **SomeClass**.

I'd appreciate any help or input, or maybe what you think is a better idea. Let me know if I need to add additional information.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm reading into extension methods, this might be useful too?

Comment: The question is a little confusing. As I understand it, the immediate solution is the one you proposed: simply ineherit `SomeClass` from `LibraryB.SimilarParentClass`. I'm not sure what you mean by _"...every time LibraryA gets updated..."_? Is it _your_ library or not? _Who_ is updating it? Maybe a little more context and real code is needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Fork library A.

Comment: The library is another developer's, I am trying to create a plugin for it. I could fork the library, but then when he updates his, I will have to reupdate everything.